# Set 2013 High Trust App StartUrl at deployment time

Tags: 2013, deployment, app

Is it possible to set the start url of a High Trust App at deployment time?

From what I can tell it looks like this the url from app manifest gets hard coded into a binary .app file at compile time.

I would like to be able to set this url at deployment time to the each environments url when it is deployed (integration, qa, prod).  Is this possible.

I have looked at Import-SPAppPackage and Install-SPApp but was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this as well and I couldn't find anything either. I ended up writing a little app to unzip the .app file change the value of the start url and then zipping it back up with the same app name. Then deploying this .app to sharepoint with the url i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options -

1. Redeploy your app with new URL.
2. Use PS to update the URL in the app manifest.

PS for option 2 -

```
 Function Update-AppManifest($appPackage, $oldUrl, $newUrl)
 {
   Add-Type -Path (Get-ChildItem "WindowsBase.dll")

   Write-Host "Opening app package '$appPackage'"

   $package = [System.IO.Packaging.Package]::Open($appPackage, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
   $manifestUri = New-Object System.Uri("/AppManifest.xml", [System.UriKind]::Relative)
   $partNameUri = [System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper]::CreatePartUri($manifestUri)
   $part = $package.GetPart($partNameUri)
   $partStream = $part.GetStream()

   Write-Host "Reading app package"
   $reader = New-Object -Type System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $partStream
   $content = $reader.ReadToEnd()

   Write-Host "===================== START: Contents before Replace ====================="
   echo $content
   Write-Host "===================== END: Contents before Replace ====================="

   Write-Host "Replacing the content '$oldUrl' with '$newUrl'"
      $content = $content.Replace($oldUrl, $newUrl)

   Write-Host "===================== START: Contents AFTER Replace ====================="
   echo $content
   Write-Host "===================== END: Contents AFTER Replace ====================="


   $partStream.Position = 0
   $partStream.SetLength(0)

   Write-Host "Updating the package file"
   $writer = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $partStream
   $writer.Write($content)
   $writer.Flush()

   $package.Close()

   Write-Host "Package updated and closed."
 }


 $purana = "https://puranaurl"
 $naya = "https://nayaurl"
 $appPackage = "path2app"

 Update-AppManifest $appPackage $purana $newUrl
```

**Note -**  you will need reference to windowsbase.dll for unzipping and updating the app.